# Pulling data from db causing 404 page not found error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to filter my views in such a way that when a specific school is chosen, pk of the school will be placed in a view function called major which would further query the db to display the proper majors corresponding to that school.

I now get a page not found 404 error, and can't figure out why.

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:Major>/', views.Major, name='Major')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    school_Major_merge = models.ManyToManyField(Major, through='School_Major')

class School_Major(models.Model):
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberofRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #delete major from the model  
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfessorName
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import professor, School, Major, School_Major

def index(request):
    schools = School.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'locate/index.html', {'schools': schools})

def Major(request, school_pk):
    #Filter to a show the association of 1 schools majors
    school_choice = Major_School.objects.filter(school_id = school_pk)
    #Filter majors names required
    majors = Major.objects.filter(id = school_choice.major_id)
    return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'majors' : majors})
```

I will post the code for the index file which pulls the schools info below, and when clicking on the school (hyperlink set) its basically suppose to pass the primary key of the school into the Major function which would then do further filtering.

```
  <ul>
    {% for list in schools %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'Major' {{list.id}}">{{list.name}}</a></li>
    <br><br>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

The primary key for the school is pulled properly but for some reason the function doesn't fire up when I click on the hyperlink for the school I receive the 404 page not found error.

Purpose of the Major function, 
1) Receive the Primary key of school, which will be passed to the M2M Table.
2) Now that ONLY majors corresponding to that school are displayed, Filter and store ONLY the majors which have the primary keys associated to the school chosen

I think the logic of my function is correct, I just can't understand again why i'm getting the 404 error.

Here is the exact error when I click the first school, which has a PK = 1

```
The current path, locate/{% url 'Major' 1/, didn't match any of these.
```

**Update:**

I went based on the suggestions below, and an example I had laying around that the format I have for the index.html is proper for the dispatcher, as well as the dispatcher is set properly aswell but WHY OH WHY does the {% still pop up I don't get it, I restarted the server thinking maybe it was bugging around but nada.

index.html

```
{% for list in schools %}
<li><a href="{% url 'Major' 'list.id' %}">{{list.name}}</a></li>
<br><br>
{%endfor%}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:school_pk>/', views.Major, name='Major')
]
```

The current path Error I'm having is still the same, but what I don't understand is after fixing the template to the proper format (I also used a example project I had as a reference that doesn't have this issue that passes a parameter) i'm not passing just the /locate/school_pk but the curly braces and the %

```
locate/ [name='index']
locate/ <int:school_pk>/ [name='Major'] <== This one
admin/
register/ [name='register']
profile/ [name='profile']
login/ [name='login']
logout/ [name='logout']
[name='blog-home']
about/ [name='blog-about']
post/<int:pk>/ [name='post-detail']
post/new/ [name='post-create']
post/<int:pk>/update/ [name='post-update']
post/<int:pk>/delete/ [name='post-delete']
user/<str:username> [name='user-posts']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, locate/{% url 'Major' 1/, didn't match any of these.
```

Notice the {% is added in there, even after I fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the template should be:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'Major' list.id %}">{{list.name}}</a></li>
```

Where the URL is something like this:

```
path('<int:school_pk>/', views.Major, name='Major')
```

For reference please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: I tried that didn't work I'll check the document reference, also I noticed I made a typo I should have %} after list.id,

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop it should be

```
<ul>
    {% for list in schools %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'Major' list.id">{{list.name}}</a></li>
        <br><br>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

Just remove double curly braces `{{ }}`

Comment: It didn't work I'm noticing now that the curly braces is trying to be queried in the url which is odd, I posted in my update

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that there was a space between this specific url dispatcher in the error message

```
locate/ [name='index']
locate/ <int:school_pk>/ [name='Major'] <== This one
admin/
register/ [name='register']
profile/ [name='profile']
login/ [name='login']
logout/ [name='logout']
[name='blog-home']
about/ [name='blog-about']
post/<int:pk>/ [name='post-detail']
post/new/ [name='post-create']
post/<int:pk>/update/ [name='post-update']
post/<int:pk>/delete/ [name='post-delete']
user/<str:username> [name='user-posts']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, locate/{% url 'Major' 1/, didn't match any of these.
```

So I added a space to the url.py which seemed to have done the trick

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(' <int:school_pk>/', views.Major, name='Major')
]
```

All my other urls in my main project are setup the same way but don't have this problem, but for some reason everything i tried it wouldn't nudge, I had to place a space in order for it to work